Tokenizer process can't access file
i am trying to use the following code
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/sugarme/tokenizer/pretrained"
    "github.com/sugarme/tokenizer"
)

func main() {
    // Download and cache pretrained tokenizer. In this case `bert-base-uncased` from Huggingface
    // can be any model with `tokenizer.json` available. E.g. `tiiuae/falcon-7b`
    configFile, err := tokenizer.CachedPath("bert-base-uncased", "tokenizer.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    tk, err := pretrained.FromFile(configFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    sentence := `The Gophers craft code using [MASK] language.`
    en, err := tk.EncodeSingle(sentence)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("tokens: %q\n", en.Tokens)
    fmt.Printf("offsets: %v\n", en.Offsets)

    
}

but i am getting this error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
tokenizer.json... 455.1 KiB/455.1 KiB completed
panic: CachedPath() failed at trying to download file: rename /.cache/tokenizer/bert-base-uncased/tokenizer.json.tmp /.cache/tokenizer/bert-base-uncased/tokenizer.json: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/my_project/tokenize.go:16 +0x87
exit status 2

any idea how to resolve this ?

Don’t use Windows. Or make sure nothing uses that file.

Likely some other process has a lock on the file, but also double-check that the user running the process has permissions to access the file, as you can occasionally get misleading file access errors.
